# Why are redundant class name qualifiers allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I came across some code like this:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(int) {}
};

struct B : A {
    void init(int i);
};

void B::init(int i) {
    A::A(i); // what is this?
}

int main() {
    B b;
    b.init(2);
}
```

This compiled and ran using VC11 beta with no errors or warnings with /W4.

The apparent intent is for calling B::init to reinitialize the B's A base subobject. I believe it actually parses as a variable declaration for a new variable named `i` with type `A`. Compiling with clang produces diagnostics:

```
ConsoleApplication1.cpp:11:14: warning: declaration shadows a local variable
        A::A(i);
             ^
ConsoleApplication1.cpp:10:22: note: previous declaration is here
    void B::init(int i) {
                     ^
ConsoleApplication1.cpp:11:14: error: redefinition of 'i' with a different type
        A::A(i);
             ^
ConsoleApplication1.cpp:10:22: note: previous definition is here
    void B::init(int i) {
                     ^
```

It seems curious that the type can be referred to with the redundant class qualification.

Also, `A::A(i)` appears to be parsed differently by VS11 and clang/gcc. If I do `A::A(b)` clang and gcc create a variable `b` of type `A` using the default constructor. VS11 errors out on that saying `b` is an unknown identifier. VS11 appears to parse `A::A(i)` as the creation of a temporary `A` using the constructor `A::A(int)` with `i` as the parameter.  When the redundant qualifier is eliminated VS parses the source as a variable declaration like clang and gcc do, and produces a similar error about shadowing the variable `i`.

This difference in parsing explains why VS11 will choke on more than a single extra qualifier; `A::A::A::A(i)`, and why, given that clang and gcc can accept one extra qualifier, any number more than one extra has the same result as one extra.

Here's another example with the redundant qualifiers in a different context. All compiler seem to parse this as a temporary construction:

```
class Foo {};

void bar(Foo const &) {}

int main() {
    bar(Foo::Foo());
}
```

1. Why are redundant qualifiers allowed at all?
2. There are some contexts where constructors can be referred to, such as the syntax for inheriting constructors (`class D : B { using B::B; };`) but VS seems to be allowing it anywhere. Is VS wrong and are clang and gcc right in how redundant qualifiers are parsed?
3. I know VS is still a fair bit behind in terms of standards compliance, but I do find it a bit surprising that modern, actively developed compilers could be so divergent, in this case resolving a redundant qualifier as the name of a constructor (even though constructors don't have names) vs. resolving redundant qualifiers simply to the type, resulting in VS constructing a temporary where the others declare a variable. It can be made even worse where `B b(A::A(i));` is parsed by clang and gcc as the most vexing parse, but VS sees it as declaring a variable `b` of type `B` with an initializer. Are there still many differences this severe?
4. Clearly, redundant qualifiers should be avoided in portable code. Is there a good way to prevent this construct from being used?

Comment: FWIW, Comeau agrees with MSVC: `A::A(j)` is a constructor call. IIRC this is on the basis that the name `A` is injected into the class namespace of `A`, and refers to the type `A` (not the constructor). But `TypeIdentifier(j)` is just another way of writing the C-style cast `(TypeIdentifier)j`, so it does in fact call a constructor. Additionally, Comeau reports "a constructor or destructor may not have its address taken", which I don't understand.

Comment: @SteveJessop But if `A::A` is referring to the type name `A` injected into the class namespace `A` doesn't `A::A` refer to a type? and then `A::A i;` must be a variable declaration, and `A::A(i);` must also be a variable declaration?

Comment: Ah, because if in doubt it's a declaration. OK, well I'm certainly confused. And surprised if/that Comeau is getting it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the phenomenon can probably be attributed to *class name injection*, as noted in ephemient's answer, for this specific example it has been outlawed by C++ language quite a while ago.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#147

The combination `A::A` is required to refer to class constructor, not to the class injected name. The `A::A(i)` is supposed to be interpreted by a compliant compiler as an illegal (and therefore meaningless) expression involving constructor name. Comeau compiler, for one example, will refuse to compile your code for that reason.

Apparently VC11 continues to treat `A::A` as a reference to the injected class name. Interestingly enough, I don't observe this problem in VS2005.

Back in the day when `A::A` was interpreted as referring to the injected name, one could declare an `A` object as

```
A::A::A::A::A::A a;
```

and so on, with arbitrary number of `A`s. But not anymore. Surprisingly, version of GCC (4.3.4?) used by ideone still suffers from this issue

http://ideone.com/OkR0F

You can try this with your version of VC11 and see if it allows that.

Comment: §3.4.3.1/2 qualifies that with "In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result ... [ *Note:* For example, the constructor is
not an acceptable lookup result in an *elaborated-type-speciﬁer* so the constructor would not be used in place
of the injected-class-name. ]", which I think defeats this point?

Comment: @ephemient Is "an acceptable lookup result" defined anywhere? For example, is it possible that a constructor lookup result for `A::A` could cause the code not to be parsed as an _elaborated-type-specifier_, and cause it instead to be parsed as a call to a constructor? If that occurred would that make a constructor "an acceptable lookup result?" Seems like there's a bit of circularity there...

Comment: @ephemient: Not really, without knowing exactly in which context it is "an acceptable lookup result". The example in that very part of the standard clearly shows that `A::A a` is en error because `A::A` *refers to the constructor*. See: it causes an error, yet it is considered "an acceptable lookup result". In case of an elaborate type specifier is not acceptable, but what other cases exist is not clear to me at the moment.

Comment: You can still do the `A::A::A::...` dance, as long as the final `A` too uses a lookup form that ignores functions (as does the lookup for a name prior a `::`). For example `struct A::A::A::A a;` can be valid for a struct `A`.

Answer (score 3):

From the ISO/IEC 14882:2011 final draft §9,

> ² The *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen.  The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself, this is known as the *injected-class-name*.

When you write

```
A::A(i);
```

it is the same as the declaration

```
A i;
```

as the extra parentheses are superfluous (you can add as many as you like) and `A::A` refers to `A`.

---

From §14.6.1,

> ¹ Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9).  The injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*.  When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself.  Otherwise, it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.

The injected class name seems to be a convenience to allow `A<...>` to be referred to as simply `A` from within the class.

Comment: It seems quite harmful to me that the injected class name is visible externally. Also it makes the syntax for inherited constructors a bit incongruous.

Comment: This answer is fine but I'm un-accepting for now because I don't want to discourage others from providing answers that may end up being more thorough.

Comment: While this answer makes sense, 5.1.1/8 says: `Where class-name :: class-name is used, and the two class-names refer to the same class, this notation names the constructor` which seems to be saying something different.