# call base-class constructor in initializer list

Tags: c++, list, constructor, base-class, initializer

i write the following code:

```
class A {
protected:

    int age;
public:
    A(int a);
};

A::A(int a){
    cout << "constructer A" << a << endl;
    age =a;
}

class B : public A{
    int id;
public:
B(int i,int a);
};
B::B(int i, int a):A::A(a)
{
    cout << "constructer B" << endl;
    id = i;
}
```

are there different between

```
B::B(int i, int a):A::A(a)
```

and

```
B::B(int i, int a):A(a)
```

?,
i know both of theme work well, but my question is what is the different

Comment: I'm puzzled that the compiler allows `A::A(a)` in the initializer list but does not allow `B b = B::B(10, 20);` to construct an object  (tested with g++ 4.7.3).

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423380/why-are-redundant-class-name-qualifiers-allowed) will shed some light.